# CSS : Hovering affect

Tags: css

I have to create a hovering effect wherein when a tab is hovered the entire background of the tab should be White. But as can be seen in below SS, [image: below SS], hovering affect is getting applied only to the text part.

I have also attached the CSS from Chrome Web developer.

[image: CSS]

HTML code generating that tab is ,

```
<li>
  <a class="last_menu" href="#"></a>
</li>
```

I have tried adjusting with `padding` element. But, text is also moving with it. I want text to be at center and only hovering to be expanded to occupy whole tab space.

Comment: Please crop your image. Not only is it taking up an unnecessary amount of space, the actual content is too miniscule to see.

Comment: Have you tried a:hover{background-color: white;} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) Go to `CSS > Display Style Information` or `<ALT+SHIFT+Y>`(it's the wand in the toolbar). Hover your mouse over the element in question to get a detailed picture of how it's being rendered. Study this. Make it your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying a class to the list item itself, then under the hover pseudoselector for that specify a white background.